# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined, in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, ticket-system

I'm trying to make a ticket system in an app, while creating this method i'm getting this weird error related to this function, and in the line where VM.state[0]._id is mentioned to be exact :

```
'use strict';
angular.module('app.modules.support')
    .controller('NewTicketController', [ 'ApiService', '$mdDialog', '$log', '$rootScope', '$mdToast',
        function (ApiService, $mdDialog, $log, $rootScope, $mdToast, states  /*, lodash */ ) {
            // PROPERTIES
            const VM = this;
            VM.gdpr = false;
            VM.public='public';
            VM.state = states,
            // METHODS

VM.createTicket = () => {
                const TICKET = {};
                const FIRST_MESSAGE = {};

                if (VM.form.$valid === true) {
                    FIRST_MESSAGE.body = VM.body.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');

                    TICKET.title = VM.title;
                    TICKET.space = VM.space;
                    /* eslint-disable camelcase */
                    VM.gdpr_phone!==''?TICKET.trace_rgpd = VM.gdpr_phone:TICKET.trace_rgpd='not';
                    TICKET.created_with = 'NeMa';
                    TICKET.viewed_by = [VM.userId];
                    TICKET.priority = 'low';
                    TICKET.id_lessor = 'AWBRcEpPV9YLqCHvv9nD'; //TODO: CHANGE THIS IN THE FUTURE
                    TICKET.events = [{
                        state_update : new Date().getTime(),
                        id_state     : VM.state[0]._id
                    }];
                    ApiService.Support.saveTicket(TICKET).then((result) => {
                        if (result.rows[0].items[0].index.created) {
                            VM.toast('Demande enregistrée');
                        }
                        FIRST_MESSAGE.id_ticket = result.rows[0].items[0].index._id;
                        ApiService.Support.saveMessage(FIRST_MESSAGE.id_ticket, FIRST_MESSAGE).then(() => {
                            $rootScope.$broadcast('/support/partialReload', FIRST_MESSAGE.id_ticket);
                            $mdDialog.hide();
                        });
                    });
                }
            };
```

any ideas how I can solve this problem ?

Comment: Where is the code that defines `VM.state`? This error is not that weird -- it is a very common error actually.

Comment: `VM.state` is `undefined` - exactly what the error says.

Comment: VM.state=states in Propreties of the function

Comment: 1) If you edit your post and put the new lines there, it'll be easier to read, and 2) still there's some info missing. Is `VM.state = states` executed before `VM.createTicket()` is called? And is `states` defined then?

Comment: I edited the code of class, I tried to change the id_state to |id_state: VM.state[VM.state.length - 1]._id] but getting cannot read the property length of undefined

Answer (score 0):

this just means "VM.state" is undefined at the time you are trying to access VM.state[0]._id; add a console.log statement to figure out why it is not defined.